# Table manipulating

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there any plugins for JQuery for manipulating with tables (inserting rows dynamically, etc). Or I have to write it by hands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [DataTables](http://datatables.net)

Answer (score 0):

Just did a quick search and found this: http://www.datatables.net/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("table tbody").append(row);
```

and

```
$("table tbody").prepend(row);
```

to add rows to a table body

Where is the data coming from?

Comment: Okay. What about resizing table dynamically?